# python matplotlib anime multi-lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

What is wrong with my code. Thanks in advance;
Help please. The code don't do what I want and draw 2 canvas;

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
from matplotlib import animation
import dateutil
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

X = ['10:00:01', '10:00:02', '10:00:03', '10:00:04', '10:00:05', '10:00:06', '10:00:07', '10:00:08', '10:00:09', '10:00:10', '10:00:11', '10:00:12']
XX = X[11]

DATES = [dateutil.parser.parse(s) for s in X]
Y1 = [90, 60, 45, 34, 56, 66, 71, 24, 46, 12, 64, 45]
Y2 = [45, 70, 25, 84, 96, 26, 41, 28, 76, 52, 34, 55]
Y3 = [40, 82, 46, 87, 03, 49, 78, 24, 65, 48, 97, 46]
Y4 = [21, 54, 75, 35, 75, 67, 24, 74, 95, 34, 30, 48]

plt.figure(figsize=(18,10), dpi=100)
plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.rc('font', family='serif', size=13)
plt_data = range(0, 100)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0.0)
plt.xticks(rotation = 35)

ax=plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks(DATES)
xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.plot(DATES, Y1, color="blue", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-")
plt.plot(DATES, Y2, color="red",  linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-")
plt.plot(DATES, Y3, color="green",  linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-")
plt.plot(DATES, Y4, color="cyan",  linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-")

plt.xlabel('$\Delta t$ $(s)$', fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('$\Delta p$ $(hPa)$', fontsize=20)
plt.autoscale(enable = True, axis = u'both', tight = False)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
fig = plt.figure()

def animate(args):
    global XX
    global Y1
    global y2
    global y3
    global y4
    global X
    global DATES

    Y1.append(int(random.random() * 100))
    Y2.append(int(random.random() * 100))
    Y3.append(int(random.random() * 100))
    Y4.append(int(random.random() * 100))
    del Y1[0]
    del Y2[0]
    del Y3[0]
    del Y4[0]

    TOP_DT1 = datetime.strptime(XX, '%H:%M:%S')
    TOP_DT1 = TOP_DT1 + timedelta(seconds=1)
    XX = TOP_DT1.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    X.append(XX)
    del X[0]
    print Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4, X

    lines = []
    lines.append(plt.plot(DATES, Y1, color="blue", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-"),)
    lines.append(plt.plot(DATES, Y2, color="red", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-"),)
    lines.append(plt.plot(DATES, Y3, color="green", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-"),)
    lines.append(plt.plot(DATES, Y4, color="cyan",  linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-"),)

    fig.canvas.draw()
    plt.pause(0.0001)

    return lines

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=2000, interval=1, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

**Error output**

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_animated'
[45, 34, 56, 66, 71, 24, 46, 12, 64, 45, 90, 6] [25, 84, 96, 26, 41, 28, 76, 52, 34, 55, 22, 50] [46, 87, 3, 49, 78, 24, 65, 48, 97, 46, 3, 4] [75, 35, 75, 67, 24, 74, 95, 34, 30, 48, 10, 64] ['10:00:03', '10:00:04', '10:00:05', '10:00:06', '10:00:07', '10:00:08', '10:00:09', '10:00:10', '10:00:11', '10:00:12', '10:00:13', '10:00:14']
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1540, in call
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 282, in resize
    self.resize_event()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1819, in resize_event
    self.callbacks.process(s, event)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 563, in process
    proxy(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 430, in call
    return mtd(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 917, in _handle_resize
    self._init_draw()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1193, in _init_draw
    self._draw_frame(next(self.new_frame_seq()))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1215, in _draw_frame
    a.set_animated(self._blit)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_animated'`

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you are expecting from your code? Also, what version of python are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7.11. I expected a graph not 2. The second but with the size of the first, and with numbers on y an times on x scrolling from right to left.

Comment: I ran it on Mac OS X (10.11.5) using Python 2.7.10 and it worked fine for me.

Comment: I'm getting 2 graphs a big one and a small one. And no anime at all.

Comment: What Operating System are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: All the major samples I tried works fine. I just can't find an example similar to my code.

Comment: Change the return from def anime(i): to return tuple(lines) don't solve.

Comment: Are you getting this error and also two graphs at the same time? Perhaps you could attach a screenshot of the graphs.

Comment: I only want one graph, but the code is creating two. I just want on x times, y values and the animation from rigth to left, new values added at right and rotate to left.

Comment: Now the code only show one graph but the anination is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The animation is still not working, but at least I only have one graph.

```
    from scipy import stats
    import numpy as np
    import random
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.dates as md
    from matplotlib import animation
    import dateutil
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    import time

    X = ['10:00:01', '10:00:02', '10:00:03', '10:00:04', '10:00:05', '10:00:06', '10:00:07', '10:00:08', '10:00:09', '10:00:10', '10:00:11', '10:00:12']
    XX = X[11]

    DATES = [dateutil.parser.parse(s) for s in X]
    Y1 = [90, 60, 45, 34, 56, 66, 71, 24, 46, 12, 64, 45]
    Y2 = [45, 70, 25, 84, 96, 26, 41, 28, 76, 52, 34, 55]
    Y3 = [40, 82, 46, 87, 03, 49, 78, 24, 65, 48, 97, 46]
    Y4 = [21, 54, 75, 35, 75, 67, 24, 74, 95, 34, 30, 48]

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,10), dpi=100)
    plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
    plt.rc('font', family='serif', size=13)
    plt_data = range(0, 100)
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0.0)
    plt.xticks(rotation = 35)

    ax=fig.gca()
    ax.set_xticks(DATES)
    xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

    plt.plot(DATES, Y1, color="blue", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-")
    plt.plot(DATES, Y2, color="red",  linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-")
    plt.plot(DATES, Y3, color="green",  linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-")
    plt.plot(DATES, Y4, color="cyan",  linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-")

    plt.xlabel('$\Delta t$ $(s)$', fontsize=20)
    plt.ylabel('$\Delta p$ $(hPa)$', fontsize=20)
    plt.autoscale(enable = True, axis = u'both', tight = False)
    plt.grid(True)
    fig.show()

    def init():
        global XX
        global Y1
        global y2
        global y3
        global y4
        global X
        global DATES

        X = ['10:00:01', '10:00:02', '10:00:03', '10:00:04', '10:00:05', '10:00:06', '10:00:07', '10:00:08', '10:00:09', '10:00:10', '10:00:11', '10:00:12']
        XX = X[11]

        DATES = [dateutil.parser.parse(s) for s in X]
        Y1 = [90, 60, 45, 34, 56, 66, 71, 24, 46, 12, 64, 45]
        Y2 = [45, 70, 25, 84, 96, 26, 41, 28, 76, 52, 34, 55]
        Y3 = [40, 82, 46, 87, 03, 49, 78, 24, 65, 48, 97, 46]
        Y4 = [21, 54, 75, 35, 75, 67, 24, 74, 95, 34, 30, 48]
        lines = []
        lines.append(plt.plot(DATES, Y1, color="blue", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-"),)
        lines.append(plt.plot(DATES, Y2, color="red", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-"),)
        lines.append(plt.plot(DATES, Y3, color="green", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-"),)
        lines.append(plt.plot(DATES, Y4, color="cyan",  linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-"),)
        return tuple(lines)

    def animate(i):
        global XX
        global Y1
        global y2
        global y3
        global y4
        global X
        global DATES

        Y1.append(int(random.random() * 100))
        Y2.append(int(random.random() * 100))
        Y3.append(int(random.random() * 100))
        Y4.append(int(random.random() * 100))
        del Y1[0]
        del Y2[0]
        del Y3[0]
        del Y4[0]

        TOP_DT1 = datetime.strptime(XX, '%H:%M:%S')
        TOP_DT1 = TOP_DT1 + timedelta(seconds=1)
        XX = TOP_DT1.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        X.append(XX)
        del X[0]
        print Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4, X

        lines = []
        lines.append(plt.plot(DATES, Y1, color="blue", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-"),)
        lines.append(plt.plot(DATES, Y2, color="red", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-"),)
        lines.append(plt.plot(DATES, Y3, color="green", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-"),)
        lines.append(plt.plot(DATES, Y4, color="cyan",  linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-"),)

        fig.canvas.draw()
        plt.pause(0.0001)

        return tuple(lines)

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=50, blit=True)
    plt.show()
```

<\code>